After working fine for 6 months - logging in via SSH will hang after entering user name...never actually log me in
I have a headless mini server running Ubuntu and as of recently, when I try to login to SSH it hangs after entering the password and never logs me in.  This is a plex server, and plex also "goes down".... (technically, it IS running though, as this has happened when I have had a session already going and could examine if it was up...however, clients cannot connect when this happens.  This all began after I was uninstalling my backup agent for Synology Active Backup for Business, and uninstalling/reinstalling intel firmware.... HOWEVER...what brought me to the server, was because backups were failing for some reason.  I had auto update on, so I am not even sure what software may have been updated, if something is causing this.
I see this in the logs, but it's Greek to me.

Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856643] BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000158
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856651] #PF: supervisor write access in kernel mode
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856654] #PF: error_code(0x0002) - not-present page
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856656] PGD 0 P4D 0
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856659] Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP NOPTI
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856661] CPU: 2 PID: 5828 Comm: kworker/2:2 Tainted: G           OE     5.15.0-118-generic #128-Ubuntu
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856665] Hardware name: AZW MINI S/MINI S, BIOS ADLNV104 02/06/2023
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856667] Workqueue: events __intel_wakeref_put_work [i915]
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856739] RIP: 0010:_raw_spin_lock_irq+0x17/0x40
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856744] Code: 5d c3 cc cc cc cc e8 e8 76 36 ff 5d c3 cc cc cc cc 66 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 fa 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 31 c0 ba 01 00 00 00 <f0> 0f b1 17 75 06 5d c3 cc cc cc cc 89 c6 e8 86 70 36 ff 66 90 5d
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856748] RSP: 0018:ffffad6300b4bdc0 EFLAGS: 00010046
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856750] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000040000
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856753] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000158
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856754] RBP: ffffad6300b4bdc0 R08: ffff8b10dba6cd30 R09: 00000000000005fe
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856756] R10: 0000000000000007 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff8b10d3055000
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856759] R13: 0000000000000158 R14: ffff8b142fb37905 R15: ffff8b142fb31a40
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856761] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8b142fb00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856764] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856766] CR2: 0000000000000158 CR3: 00000001df810000 CR4: 0000000000750ee0
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856768] PKRU: 55555554
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856770] Call Trace:
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856772]  <TASK>
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856774]  ? show_trace_log_lvl+0x1d6/0x2ea
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856778]  ? show_trace_log_lvl+0x1d6/0x2ea
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856781]  ? px_release+0x27/0xd0 [i915]
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856848]  ? show_regs.part.0+0x23/0x29
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856852]  ? __die_body.cold+0x8/0xd
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856856]  ? __die+0x2b/0x37
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856859]  ? page_fault_oops+0x13b/0x170
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856865]  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x321/0x670
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856869]  ? exc_page_fault+0x77/0x170
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856874]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856881]  ? _raw_spin_lock_irq+0x17/0x40
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856886]  px_release+0x27/0xd0 [i915]
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.856985]  i915_px_cache_release+0x54/0x80 [i915]
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.857088]  __gt_park+0xb5/0x100 [i915]
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.857184]  ____intel_wakeref_put_last+0x29/0x90 [i915]
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.857261]  __intel_wakeref_put_work+0x3d/0x50 [i915]
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.857340]  process_one_work+0x228/0x3d0
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.857345]  worker_thread+0x53/0x420
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.857348]  ? process_one_work+0x3d0/0x3d0
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.857352]  kthread+0x127/0x150
BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000158#PF: error_code(0x0002) - not-present page
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.857357]  ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.857362]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.857368]  </TASK>
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.857370] Modules linked in: tls xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE xt_tcpudp xt_mark nft_compat nft_chain_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nft_counter nf_tables nfnetlink cmac nls_utf8 cifs cifs_arc4 cifs_md4 fscache netfs snd_sof_pci_int>
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.857433]  scsi_dh_alua msr efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear i915(OE) spi_pxa2xx_plat>
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.857508] CR2: 0000000000000158
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.857512] ---[ end trace 900ca9f64c723d07 ]---
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.953769] RIP: 0010:_raw_spin_lock_irq+0x17/0x40
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.953776] Code: 5d c3 cc cc cc cc e8 e8 76 36 ff 5d c3 cc cc cc cc 66 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 fa 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 31 c0 ba 01 00 00 00 <f0> 0f b1 17 75 06 5d c3 cc cc cc cc 89 c6 e8 86 70 36 ff 66 90 5d
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.953780] RSP: 0018:ffffad6300b4bdc0 EFLAGS: 00010046
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.953783] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000040000
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.953786] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000158
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.953788] RBP: ffffad6300b4bdc0 R08: ffff8b10dba6cd30 R09: 00000000000005fe
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.953790] R10: 0000000000000007 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff8b10d3055000
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.953792] R13: 0000000000000158 R14: ffff8b142fb37905 R15: ffff8b142fb31a40
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.953794] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8b142fb00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.953797] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.953799] CR2: 0000000000000158 CR3: 0000000107d94000 CR4: 0000000000750ee0
Aug 20 17:45:01 inserthostnamehere kernel: [162797.953801] PKRU: 55555554



Anyone else had a similar issue?
I am curious as where to look, or if anyone can point me in a good direction.
Annnnnnnnnnnnd...when I started typing this, I was trying to login to SSH and it was hanging.  By the time I finished, it had logged me in.  Does this sound like anything to anyone? Just need a direction to go

Seems like a Kernel memory error. I had those once, and for me it helped to install ECC memory.
